# Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my asp.net c# web application, I m unable to find where exactly in the code, this exception (Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.)is raised. The URL where the exception is coming is of format as below

http://somedomain.com/sepsisvte/sepsis.aspx?4040431page=2

If the problem is related to the structure of the URL then there are URL like below where I m not getting any exception at all

http://somedomain.com/sepsisvte/sepsis.aspx?4020894page=2
http://somedomain.com/sepsisvte/sepsis.aspx?4020894page=3

Its a quite large application and Its really difficult to find the origin of error. Any ideas?

The stacktrace is as below

> [UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be
>   determined.]    System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape,
>   UriKind uriKind) +5462488    System.Uri..ctor(String uriString) +20
>   umbraco.presentation.requestModule.rewrite404Url(String url, String
>   querystring, Boolean returnQuery) +265
>   umbraco.presentation.requestModule.Application_BeginRequest(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +237
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +68    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75

Comment: That *is* a valid input string for the URI constructor. Are you **sure** that is the URI throwing an exception? Why can't you find *where* in the code the exception is being raised? Do you not have a stack trace?

Comment: @Snixtor I have added the stack trace in the exception. There is an anchor element which links to this page (http://somedomain.com/sepsisvte/sepsis.aspx?4040431page=2). When I click that I get the above errro. thanks

Comment: That makes it look like the fault probably lies in your umbraco config.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your url contains this "?404". Umbraco searches each url for this text, and if it exists, it rewrite the url. Check the source code here: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/28576630/, search for this method: rewrite404Url.

One of the solutions is to try to prefix your query string key with underscore.